# I am getting Allocation of Resources Without Limits or Throttling error

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, endpoint

I am getting the **Allocation of Resources Without Limits or Throttling** errors when I am testing my code. I can't understand how to implement this Throttling with my route.

I have tried with middleware but the same issue with when I test it with snyk.

***This endpoint handler performs an operation and does not use a rate-limiting mechanism. It may enable the attackers to perform Denial-of-service attacks. Consider using a rate-limiting middleware such as express-limit.***

can anyone explain how to implement it with my route?

here is the endpoint code.

```
edit: async (req, res) => {
  const editCatagoryId = req.params.slug;
  try {
    const category = await Category.findOne({ where: { slug: editCatagoryId } });
    if(category) {
      res.render('admin/category/edit', { title: 'Category Edit', category });
    } else {
      req.flash('error', 'Something Wrong with Category or Not found !');
      return res.status(404).redirect('back');
    }
  } catch (err) {
    req.flash('error', 'Something Wrong with Editing Category !');
    return res.status(302).render('back');
  }
},
```

Comment: If your service is going to be behind a gateway or reverse proxy such as haproxy, this should be handled at that level and not in your nodejs app.

Comment: @hanut I know but in this case, the code is running Godaddy shared hosting, this kind of solution is not available. I need to do something manually.

Comment: If you are using express try https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-rate-limit

Comment: @hanut yes, i am using express and also using this package,